# How to serve different web apps using one domain name in Apache?

Tags: ruby, django, python-3.x, apache, virtualhost

I'm currently trying to deploy my Django 2.0 App on an Apache Web Server. However I'm experiencing difficulties in configuring it because my Virtual Host configuration overrides other Virtual Hosts which is used by other projects (Ruby and PHP WebApps). We only have one domain name at the moment so I cannot use other domain names to host my app.

Is it possible to serve different kind of apps with one domain name using Apache Virtual Hosts?

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: Can please give me an example of a Virtual Host Configuration? I'm really confused with the ones in the Apache website.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can only have 1 VirtualHost (one domain, one port, one IP), you cannot create additionnal VH.  You need to "split" the paths to the different applications some other way.

Let assume www.example.com:

```
ServerRoot "/some/path/apache"

[...] OTHER LoadModule directives [...]    
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so

Listen *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com

    # Logs
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog "logs/www.example.com_access-log" combined
    ErrorLog "logs/www.example.com_error-log"

    # Index file.  Add as many as required for your applications
    <IfModule dir_module>    
        DirectoryIndex index.html
    </IfModule>

    # Where the documents are
    DocumentRoot "/some/path/apache/htdocs"

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory "/some/path/apache/htdocs">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This VirtualHost is a basic configuration for the www.example.com domain.  Now you want to have Ruby, PHP WebApps and Django 2.0 App under that single domain.  You have 3 choices:

1. Get 1 domain per application, not applicable here, that is your question.
2. Make a sub-directory in htdocs, and a path in the URI for each application.
3. Put each application in some directory, not under `DocumentRoot` and use `Alias`.
4. Use sub-domains.

---

1. Not applicable.

---

2. Sub-directory and path

Create `/some/path/apache/htdocs/Ruby`, put your Ruby app. here.
Will be accessed via `http://www.example.com/Ruby`

Create `/some/path/apache/htdocs/PHPWebApps`, put your PHP app. here.
Will be accessed via `http://www.example.com/PHPWebApps`

Create `/some/path/apache/htdocs/Django`, put your Django app. here.
Will be accessed via `http://www.example.com/Django`

The URI value must match the directory value.

---

3. In some directory, use `Alias`

If you do not need, or want the URI to match the directory name (like in 2.), use Alias.

Create `/SOME_DIR_FOR_Ruby`, put your Ruby app. here.
Add `Alias "/Ruby" "/SOME-DIR-FOR-Ruby"`
Will be accessed via `http://www.example.com/Ruby`

Create `/SOME_DIR_FOR_PHPWebApps`, put your PHP app. here.
Add `Alias "/PHPWebApps" "/SOME_DIR_FOR_PHPWebApps"`
Will be accessed via `http://www.example.com/PHPWebApps`

Create `/SOME_DIR_FOR_Django`, put your Django app. here.
Add `Alias "/Django" "/SOME_DIR_FOR_Django"`
Will be accessed via `http://www.example.com/Django`

---

4. Use sub-domains

This is where you could use multiple VirtualHosts.  But you have to be able to create sub-domains.  This is done either via a DNS configuration, or through your hosting provider.

You could setup http://ruby.example.com, http://php.example.com, http://django.example.com.  Each of these will have 1 VirtualHost, but will all be mapped to the same IP in the DNS.

Then setup 3 VH:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ruby.example.com

    # Logs
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog "logs/ruby.example.com_access-log" combined
    ErrorLog "logs/ruby.example.com_error-log"

    # Index file.  Add as many as required for your applications
    <IfModule dir_module>    
        DirectoryIndex index.html
    </IfModule>

    # Where the documents are
    DocumentRoot "/some/path/apache/htdocs/Ruby"

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory "/some/path/apache/htdocs/Ruby">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName php.example.com

    # Logs
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog "logs/php.example.com_access-log" combined
    ErrorLog "logs/php.example.com_error-log"

    # Index file.  Add as many as required for your applications
    <IfModule dir_module>    
        DirectoryIndex index.html
    </IfModule>

    # Where the documents are
    DocumentRoot "/some/path/apache/htdocs/php"

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory "/some/path/apache/htdocs/php">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName django.example.com

    # Logs
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog "logs/django.example.com_access-log" combined
    ErrorLog "logs/django.example.com_error-log"

    # Index file.  Add as many as required for your applications
    <IfModule dir_module>    
        DirectoryIndex index.html
    </IfModule>

    # Where the documents are
    DocumentRoot "/some/path/apache/htdocs/django"

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory "/some/path/apache/htdocs/django">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

On Apache 2.2, you have to add `NameVirtualHost *:80`, in Apache 2.4, nothing, it is always "on".

All these values can be changed as you like, this is just an example to explain the concept.

Comment: Very detailed answer. Some parts can be elaborated more. Like how to use "Sub-directory and path".